# How often should you compact an SQL CE database?

Tags: sql-server-ce

Is there even a need to periodically compact SQL CE databases? Will auto shrink suffice? Our average database size is about 100Mb, with large users hitting 400-500Mb (but those are very rare). If we do have to compact manually, how do we tell when we should? Is there a way to tell the fragmentation level or percent of wasted space programmatically? If not, what other threshold can we use?

The previous version of the product was built on an (*gasp*) MS Access database, so we had to periodically compact just to keep it working.

Comment: You might have better luck asking this question on http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would imagine that, if you can set up the database so that it automatically shrinks and repairs as needed, that is pretty darn thorough.  It is why there is a dearth of literature about best practices; there is a prevailing assumption that it "just works."  So any guidance you get in this area is going to be vague.

Here is a (partial) quote from a webcast at http://www.microsoft.com/web/library/Details.aspx?id=sql-server-2008-compact-express-depoly-manage

> Maintaining your SQL Server Express
>   Editions is fairly similar to managing
>   any other multi-user database, meaning
>   that we have the option to go in and
>   deal with file groups, we can deal
>   with backup options and recovery
>   models and what not.  [But] when we deal
>   with compact editions or SQL Service
>   CE, we don’t have nearly as many
>   options. Really, the only options we
>   have is how we want to deal with
>   shrink and repair.

Here is another one from MSDN at 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms838028.aspx#youcantakeitwithyou_sqlserverce_topic4

Notice that they give good detail about the architecture of the database, but the still don't give a maintenance schedule.  Their advice: *do it when the database begins to get slow.*  Also note that this advice is circa 2005, and things have improved since then; i.e. the maintenance procedures have now been automated.

> **Keep Your House (or Database) in Order**
>  Another big factor in the
>   performance of large databases in SQL
>   Server CE 2.0 is the organization of
>   the database structure itself. As your
>   application modifies the contents of
>   the database, the records become more
>   randomly distributed within the
>   database file structure. This factor
>   is especially true after a large
>   number of inserts and deletes. To
>   ensure optimal access to the database,
>   compact the database after any
>   substantial change to the contents.
>
> In addition to recovering unused
>   space, performing a compact on the
>   database has two notable impacts on
>   performance: first, it stores all
>   table records in order by their
>   primary key; second, it updates the
>   statistics used by the query
>   processor.
>
> Ordering the records by primary key
>   can notably improve primary key
>   access. This is due to the
>   page-oriented nature of SQL Server CE
>   (and most other databases). Rather
>   than loading individual records from
>   the database into memory, SQL Server
>   CE loads blocks of records called
>   pages. When the database records are
>   grouped in order by primary key,
>   loading the page containing one record
>   automatically loads those records with
>   similar primary key values. For most
>   applications, this results in what's
>   referred to as a good "hit rate,"
>   which means that when your application
>   goes to access successive database
>   records, there is a strong likelihood
>   that the page containing those records
>   is already in memory and can be
>   directly accessed. When records are
>   more randomly distributed, as often
>   happens after a large number of
>   inserts and deletes, there is a poor
>   hit rate requiring SQL Server CE to
>   retrieve more pages from the database
>   file to access the same number of
>   records.
>
> The query processor statistics
>   influence how the query processor
>   determines the best method for
>   locating records. Decisions like
>   whether to use a key or do a
>   sequential scan to locate a particular
>   record are all influenced by the query
>   processor statistics. As the
>   statistics become stale, there is an
>   increased likelihood that the query
>   processor may make a less than optimal
>   decision. Performing a compact
>   refreshes these statistics.

I sympathize with your experience with Access databases.  However, I think you will find that your experience with SQL Server CE bears little resemblance.